# How do in know that my pdf file loading is completed

Tags: jquery, pdf.js

I am trying to set `window.print()` on my page under document.ready function, but it says that 'Document is still not ready for print'. So now who cant i detect that my pdf is loaded ?

Comment: Tried . but no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) which will execute the `checkReadyState()` function every `200` milliseconds. `checkReadyState` will execute `window.print()` once the [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) is `complete`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function isDocumentReady() {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            window.focus();
            window.print();
            window.close();
        } else {
            setTimeout(isDocumentReady, 200); 
        }
    }

    isDocumentReady();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this must be work but not under document ready

```
  $(window).load(function() {
         alert('Loaded');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try `textlayerrendered` event mentioned in [pdfjs git-repo](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/5601). Here is an example:

```
document.addEventListener('textlayerrendered', function (e) {
    if (e.detail.pageNumber === PDFViewerApplication.page) {
        // finished rendering
    }
}, true);
```